# Calculate viewport coordinates given northeast and southwest

Tags: google-maps, math, coordinates

I'm using google maps to retrieve the northeast(top-right) and southwest(bottom-left) coordinates of the viewport. How can I calculate the northwest(top-left) and southeast(bottom-right) coordinates?

Comment: I suppose getting the north from northeast and the west from soutwest, would yield nortwest. Same for southeast.

Comment: Hello @GabyakaG.Petrioli. That helped me find the solution. It is reversed though. The west from southwest is the new east, the south from southwest is the new north etc. So in the end I can calculate the missing coordinates. Your comment helped me greatly, can you please post an answer so I can accept?

Comment: It is a duplicate alright, but I searched and just couldn't find it. Don't know if the downvote is justified, but ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to combine the relevant parts, so getting the north from northeast and the west from southwest, would yield northwest. Same for southeast.

You mention in the comment that they are actually reversed, that the west is the new east etc. That is more likely a confusion from the fact that the [`LatLngBounds`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds) objects contains SW/NE and not NE/SW.